# Why is $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$ important?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

To start off, I understand the proof behind this identity, and I can visualize it in my head with the unit circle.

But I read this quote:

> They only need to remember three facts – that $\sin 30^\circ = ½$ , that $\tan 45^\circ =1$, and that $\sin^2x + \cos^2x =1$ .  Just about everything else they need to know about trigonometry can be derived from these.

and I realized I don't have a complete understanding on *practical* use of the identity.  Therefore I am looking for an explanation and some practical examples on why it is so important.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since $\sin30^\circ=1/2$ and $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$, what is $\cos30^\circ$ ?

Comment: $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$  is basically just the Pythagorean identity ($a^2 + b^2 = c^2$) expressed in Trigonometric terms instead of Algebraic terms.  And that's important because the Pythagorean theorem is the basis for almost all trigonometry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "special angles" in trig are $0^\circ$, $30^\circ$, $45^\circ$, $60^\circ$, and $90^\circ$ (and their counterparts in quadrants II, III, and IV).

Presumably, the sines and cosines at $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$ are obvious to the quoted author, so the quotation boils-down what's needed to remember values at the remaining angles to three facts.

- "$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$" allows for conversion between sines and cosines. Always handy.
- "$\sin 30^\circ = 1/2$" immediately gives $\cos 60^\circ =1/2$. (Complementary angles are cool like that, since "cosine" *means* "complementary sine".) With the help of the Pythagorean identity above, we also get $\cos 30^\circ = \sin 60^\circ = \sqrt{3}/2$. (If you're going to commit any of these to memory, it makes sense to choose the simple fraction, $1/2$. Personally, I think remembering "$\cos 60^\circ = 1/2$" is easier, because I can "see" it more easily in dropping a perpendicular from the top vertex of an equilateral triangle.)
- "$\tan 45^\circ=1$" encodes information about the remaining special angle, saying that (in Quadrant I) $\sin 45^\circ = \cos 45^\circ$. Again with the help of the Pythagorean identity, we have $1 = \sin^2 45^\circ + \cos^2 45^\circ = 2 \sin^2 45^\circ$, so that $\sin 45^\circ = \cos 45^\circ = 1/\sqrt{2}$.

So, the three facts help to recover a total of *seven* facts. And then getting the remaining secants, tangents, cosecants, and cotangents is a simple matter of using various ratios. The sine-cosine Pythagorean identity also gives rise to the others, by dividing-through by $\cos^2\theta$ or $\sin^2\theta$ ...

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta} + \frac{\cos^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta} = \frac{1}{\cos^2\theta} \quad &\to \quad \tan^2\theta + 1 = \sec^2\theta \\[6pt]
\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta} + \frac{\cos^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta} = \frac{1}{\sin^2\theta} \quad &\to \quad 1 + \cot^2\theta = \csc^2\theta
\end{align}$$

... reducing pressure to memorize all three relations.

There are other (and better?) ways to remember this stuff, but the basic point is that *there's a good deal of informational redundancy in trig*. While it may seem like there are a zillion different things to memorize, it doesn't take long to realize that one can focus on a (very) few key facts and re-derive the rest on demand.

Comment: This is an awesome explanation.  Everything I was hoping for and more.  I'm actually going to print this out and share with a classmate.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

It's importance is in its equivalence to Pythagoras' Theorem. It shows that the curve $(\cos t,\sin t)$ traces the unit circle. It relates values of one function in terms of the other.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I see.  So in regard to the unit circle, I guess it's like a more fleshed-out Pythagorean Theorem?  Since the C^2 would stay a constant 1?  I was actually originally asking more about its uses when deriving other useful, important identities.  But this is a great point too